# Sqoop job unable to work with Hadoop Credential API

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have stored my database passwords in Hadoop CredentialProvider.

Sqoop import from terminal is working fine, successfully fetching the password from CredentialProvider.

```
sqoop import
-Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/vijay/myPassword.jceks
--table myTable -m 1 --target-dir /user/vijay/output  --delete-target-dir --username vijay  --password-alias db2-dev-password
```

But when I try to setup as a Sqoop job, it is unable to recognize the -`Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path` argument.

```
sqoop job --create my-sqoop-job -- import --table myTable -m 1 --target-dir /user/vijay/output  --delete-target-dir --username vijay  -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/vijay/myPassword.jceks --password-alias
```

Following is the error message:

```
14/04/05 13:57:53 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
14/04/05 13:57:53 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/vijay/myPassword.jceks
14/04/05 13:57:53 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --password-alias
14/04/05 13:57:53 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: db2-dev-password
```

I couldn't find any special instructions in [Sqoop User Guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_job_literal) for configuring Hadoop credential API with Sqoop Job.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re positioning the Sqoop parameters solve the problem.

```
sqoop job -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/vijay/myPassword.jceks --create my-sqoop-job -- import --table myTable -m 1 --target-dir /user/vijay/output  --delete-target-dir --username vijay   --password-alias myPasswordAlias
```

Place the Hadoop credential before the Sqoop job keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sqoop job command is not proper, i.e. --password-alias is incomplete.
Please execute below command in your Hadoop server

```
hadoop credential list -provider jceks://hdfs/user/vijay/myPassword.jceks
```

Add the output in below Sqoop job command

```
sqoop job --create my-sqoop-job -- import --table myTable -m 1 --target-dir /user/vijay/output  --delete-target-dir --username vijay  -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/vijay/myPassword.jceks --password-alias <<output of above command>>
```

Comment: Hadoop credential stores the encrypted password in a secured location. Even after providing password alias also problem exists.